# How to disable assembly during debugging in Trace32?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I want to disable assembly and see pure C/C++ code during debugging using Trace32.

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The command `Mode` allows to switch the display mode.

```
Mode.Asm   : Assembly only
Mode.Hll   : Source code only
Mode.Mix   : Assembly and source code
```

The current mode also determines whether a step executes an assembly instruction or a source code block.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mode button, which is used to switch enable/disable assembly in debugger.